# Error while installing lua-nginx-module

Tags: linux, nginx, lua

I want to install openrestys lua-nginx-module to my Nginx Installation.
I tried steps from
https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module
and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50357732/adding-lua-module-to-nginx

I completed the steps mentioned and when i started the Nginx server, I get the below error

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-39-216 conf.d]$ 
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-39-216 conf.d]$ sudo service nginx start
Starting nginx: nginx: [alert] detected a LuaJIT version which is not OpenResty's; many optimizations will be disabled and performance will be compromised (see https://github.com/openresty/luajit2 for OpenResty's LuaJIT or, even better, consider using the OpenResty releases from https://openresty.org/en/download.html)
nginx: [error] lua_load_resty_core failed to load the resty.core module from https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-core; ensure you are using an OpenResty release from https://openresty.org/en/download.html (rc: 2, reason: module 'resty.core' not found:
    no field package.preload['resty.core']
    no file '../lua-resty-core/lib/resty/core.lua'
    no file '../lua-resty-lrucache/lib/resty/core.lua'
    no file './resty/core.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/luajit-2.0.5/resty/core.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/resty/core.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/resty/core/init.lua'
    no file './resty/core.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/resty/core.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
    no file './resty.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/resty.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so')    
                                                       [  OK  ]
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-39-216 conf.d]$ 
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-39-216 conf.d]$
```

The alert part is fine but I am worried about the error.

Do I need to do some additional configuration.
In My case I cannot install openresty instead of Nginx.

I tried adding it as dynamic module. I even tried with add module and compiling the Nginx. The issue remained the same.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

When we set the option lua_load_resty_core to off in nginx.conf. The error is gone

```
lua_load_resty_core off
```

Reference:

```
https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/issues/1509
```